# VB to control keyboard

Tags: vba

I am looking for a VB script to send the following keyboard commands:

Ctrl+w

If anyone can assist me I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the SendKeys function:

```
SendKeys "^w", True ' ^ indicates holding 'Ctrl', second parameter is 'Wait'
```

More resources:

[Using AppActivate and Sendkeys in VBA shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675281/using-appactivate-and-sendkeys-in-vba-shell-command)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5037